# Custom Model Binder not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding, custom-model-binder

I've been working on an MVC project that has a complex model with several nested classes, and one class has another class nested in it. I can get all of the other complex types to update correctly, but this last one never updates correctly. I've made sure to register its custom model binder, which gets executed and returns an object with the proper values assigned to its properties, but the original model never gets updated.

I've snipped out everything that works, leaving my structure only below:

**Classes**

```
public class Case
{
    public Case()
    {
        PersonOfConcern = new Person();
    }

    public Person PersonOfConcern { get; set; }
}

[ModelBinder(typeof(PersonModelBinder))]
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        NameOfPerson = new ProperName();
    }

    public ProperName NameOfPerson { get; set; }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(ProperNameConverter))]
public class ProperName : IComparable, IEquatable<string>
{
    public ProperName()
        : this(string.Empty)
    { }

    public ProperName(string fullName)
    {
        /* snip */
    }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

**Model Binder**

```
public class PersonModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(Person))
        {
            HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
            string prefix = bindingContext.ModelName + ".";

            if (request.Form.AllKeys.Contains(prefix + "NameOfPerson"))
            {
                return new Person()
                {
                    NameOfPerson = new ProperName(request.Form.Get(prefix + "NameOfPerson"))
                };
            }
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    if (CurrentUser.HasAccess)
    {
        Case item = _caseData.Get(id);

        if (TryUpdateModel(item, "Case", new string[] { /* other properties removed */ }, new string[] { "PersonOfConcern" })
            && TryUpdateModel(item.PersonOfConcern, "Case.PersonOfConcern"))
        {
            // ... Save here.
        }
    }
}
```

I'm at my wits' end. The `PersonModelBinder` gets executed and returns the correct set of values, but the model never gets updated. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? I'm having the exact same problem now.

Comment: Well, yes...but I solved the problem by changing my approach. I moved to a rudimentary ViewModel instead. Now, I nest classes in my Model classes, but I just use .NET primitives in my ViewModel classes and, in my HttpPost actions, I map the ViewModel data over to the Model. I could post this with some other information as an answer, if you'd like more detail.

Comment: Great, I ended up finding a similar workaround as well. Thanks so much for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add it in global asax on Application_Start

```
 ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(PersonModelBinder ), new PersonModelBinder ());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that. My custom model binder wouldn't be called at all if I hadn't added the binder.